# How to set photo field as not mandatory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Iam new to rails, I have an image field in my form. But i did not make it as mandatory field. But when i try to bypass it and submit the form it shows an error. I am posting my error below.

When i add if params[:contact] && params[:contact][:photo] iam getting error, that is because it is trying to access the hash which is empty to avoid that i have added params[:contact][:photo].original_filename = "empty.jpg" but it also throws error

NoMethodError in ContactsController#create
undefined method `original_filename' for nil:NilClass

```
private
def func
    name=params[:contact][:photo].original_filename
    directory= "public/data"
    return path = File.join(directory,name)                                             end
```

TypeError in  ContactsController#create
no implicit conversion of nil into String

```
def contact_params
    File.open(func,"wb") { |f| f.write(params[:contact][:photo].read) }
    params.require(:contact).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :gender, :email_id, :mobile_number, :address)
end
```

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: inspect your params to see what is passed to the controller

Answer (score 0):

Check if `params[:contact][:photo]` was actually passed to your controller before trying to access it.

```
private
def func
  if params[:contact] && params[:contact][:photo]
    name=params[:contact][:photo].original_filename
    directory= "public/data"
    return path = File.join(directory,name)
  else
    return nil # or whatever you'd like to return if no filename is passed
  end
end
```

end

I'd suggest checking out the [Action Controller Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) (and the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) in general) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have tried using the if loop as you mentioned, but it throws an error. Posting my error below and i want to use an blank contact image incase the image is not provided, i have tried it but its not working                                        TypeError in ContactsController#create
no implicit conversion of nil into String


          
 
    def contact_params
  File.open(func,"wb") { |f| f.write(params[:contact][:photo].read) }
  params.require(:contact).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :gender, :email_id, :mobile_number, :address)
 end
end

Comment: This is an entirely different issue, because it seems like the error is in your `create` method. Could you please add your `create` and `contact_params` methods to your question?

Comment: Iam posting that below
def create
  contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  name=params[:contact][:photo].original_filename
  if contact.save
   contact.update(:photo => name )
   redirect_to @contact
  else
   render 'new'
  end
 end


def contact_params
  File.open(func,"wb") { |f| f.write(params[:contact][:photo].read) }
  params.require(:contact).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :gender, :email_id, :mobile_number, :address)
 end

Comment: A couple of things. First, when you're adding a function, please add it to your question. A function in a comment is unreadable. Second, you're doing the exact same thing that you were doing in `func`. Every time you try to call a function, method, attribute, etc. on `params[:contact][:photo]`, you need to make sure that the photo exists. Please make the change I suggested above every time you try to get the original filename of a contact's photo.

Comment: @suganyasangith any luck?

Comment: I could n't fix it iam trying, still its returning the same error message. Will you please tell how to set an empty profile image in case the image is not provided.

Comment: This line checks if the image is present: `if params[:contact] && params[:contact][:photo]`. Could you please edit your question and add any errors you're still finding?